# Delete unused network from Windows 10 Settings Panel

Tags: networking, windows-10, ethernet

I have a small and harmless issue; I only have one Ethernet connection through which I access my home network and the Internet. One time I rebooted the router and now in the Windows 10 Settings Panel under the "Ethernet" section, two connections appear, my actual and fully working connection and another unnamed and useless one that appeared that one time.
My question is, how do I delete the other useless connection? It doesn't show up anywhere else, and I couldn't find it in the Windows registry.

Thanks in advance.

I'm attaching an screenshot of the Ethernet section of the Settings Panel, I'm sorry it's in Italian but it shouldn't be a problem. The circled one is the culprit.

[image: Screen]

Comment: Just delete the adapter in question.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an adapter associated to that interface, I tried to disable all the adapters I have, but it remains there.

Comment: Can you translated the circled text.  Since questions are expected to be English, the same policy, follows text in screenshots for the most part.

Comment: I'm sorry but I just couldn't install a language pack just for this reason.
The circled text just says "Internet connection not available".

Answer (score 1):

On the list `Impostazioni correlate` (English: `Related settings`) click `Modifica opzioni scheda` (English: `Change adapter options`). Then click on unwanted adapter and click on removal option, which should be above.

Comment: In the "Change Adapter Options" section that adapter is not present, there are only two adapters, one for Bluetooth and one for the working Ethernet. I tried to disable both but the unnamed interface remains there.

Answer (score 1):

Open Run by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. Type `ncpa.cpl` and press enter. 
Network Connection Window will be opened and then select the unwanted adapter and then delete it.

[image: Screenshot]